# Visualforce Detail Page buttons in Lightning?

Tags: lightning, custom-button, custom-actions

I have a Visualforce Detail page button in Classic UI which I would like to make available in , can anyone suggest how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

A visualforce detail page button is available in lightning but adopt one of these to surface to your users and make it lightning ready

You will need to do one of the following

1. Make your visualforce lightning ready with new winter 18 tag as below

> apex:page lightningStylesheets="true">

Also makes sure available in lightning checkbox is checked .

2 . Alternatively create a quick action and associate your vf page with the quick action

Comment: When trying your first answer I get this error: `Unsupported attribute lightningstylesheets in <apex:page>`. I have also tried creating a quick action and added to my page layout but it still isn't displayed.

Comment: @MCNinja You will need to be on winter 18 org for that . Adding a quick action is not sufficient .Edit the page layout you need and drag the quick action .Hope that helps